# Contar los estatus mediante el count en postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, count

Tengo la siguente consulta donde quiero agregar una columna con el total
de registros que tengan estatus Vigente, pero al ejecutarla me arroja el
siguiente error :
"ERROR:  column "terceros.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2: terceros.name as nombreRuta,"

```
select
terceros.name as nombreRuta,
terceros.name2 as nombrePromotora,
count(terceros.em_rh_status) as ToTalvigente,
(
        CASE 
            WHEN terceros.em_rh_status = 'AC' THEN 'VIGENTE'
            WHEN terceros.em_rh_status = 'BA' THEN 'BAJA'
            WHEN terceros.em_rh_status = 'CE' THEN 'CERRADO'
            ELSE 'VIGENTE'
        END
        ) as estatus,
         TRUNC((terceros.em_fs_porcentcom1 / 100),2) AS COMISION,
         (select name from c_bpartner bt where bt.c_bpartner_id = terceros.em_fs_supervisorid) as supervisor,
         (select name from c_bpartner bt where bt.c_bpartner_id = terceros.em_fs_ejecutiveid) as ejecutivo,
         (select name from c_bpartner bt where bt.c_bpartner_id = terceros.em_fs_coordinadorid) as cordinador
from fs_routeline ruta
inner join c_bpartner terceros on terceros.c_bpartner_id = ruta.managerid
group by terceros.em_rh_status
```

Comment: Cuando usas funciones de agregación, SQL exige que añadas al group by los campos que proyectes en el select y que no estén en dicha función. Es decir, name y name2

Comment: Gracias por darme la solución al error, ejecute la consulta pero solo me contabiliza de 1 en 1.

Answer (score 0):

En base al error y la contribución de AlfaBravo se agrego la siguiente query :

```
    group by terceros.name2,terceros.name,terceros.em_rh_status,terceros.em_fs_porcentcom1,     terceros.em_fs_supervisorid,terceros.em_fs_ejecutiveid,terceros,em_fs_coordinadorid;
```